# Dynamic placeholder HTML form

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I want to add a placeholder to my html form based on a select of that form.

```
<fieldset id="productEditPanel">
    <legend>Edit a Product</legend>
    <form method="POST" action="/admin/api/prod/edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="prodEditPId">Product *</label>
        <div>
            <select id="prodEditPId" name="pid" required>
                <option value="">Please select a product</option>
            {{#each prod}}
                <option value="{{pid}}">{{name}}</option>
            {{/each}}
            </select>
        </div>

        <!-- 
            Design the form for editing a product's catid, name, price, description and image   
            - the original values/image should be prefilled in the relevant elements (i.e. <input>, <select>, <textarea>, <img>)
            - prompt for input errors if any, then submit the form
        -->

        <label for="prodEditName">Name *</label>
        <div><input id="prodEditName" type="text" name="name" required pattern="^[\w- ']+$" /></div>

        <label for="prodEditPrice">Price *</label>
        <div><input id="prodEditPrice" type="number" step="0.05" name="price" required pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$" /></div>

        <label for="prodEditDescription">Description</label>
        <div><textarea id="prodEditDescription" name="description" pattern="^[\w- ',\r\n]+$"></textarea></div>

        <label for="prodEditImage">Image *</label>
        <div><input id="prodEditImage" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"> required /></div>

        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

I'm using node.js and i'm confused on how to receive the specific data on the specific product.

This is my backend.js to handle the data retrieval at the start for the select:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
// async fetch data from SQL, render page when ready
pool.query('SELECT * FROM categories', function (error, categories) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).end();
        return;
    }
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM products', function (error, products) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).end();
            return;
        }
        res.render('admin-panel', {
            layout: 'admin',
                title: 'IERG4210 Shop43 Admin',
                cat: categories.rows,
                prod: products.rows
        });

    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as a simple ajax call...

for `onchange` event of `select` you have to call a javascript method with the product id.

From the method, you have to make ajax request to your nodejs server with the provided id. And on server you have to make a new route for serving the request which will return the values in json.

Now on javascript ajax method callback, you have to put values in your document elements.

Hope it will help you.

Thanks.